# Using only .woff @font-face to remove clutter?

Tags: fonts, font-face, webfonts

I was looking at the canIuse site today and noticed that the woff font-face type is supported in the grand majority of browsers. Does this mean I can remove all the other types if I don't care about supporting IE 8 < or Opera mini?

I'm assuming that browsers only use one http request to grab the file they use instead of having multiple requests for each font-face?

http://caniuse.com/#search=woff